# Assigning value 20 to next address in the memory using *(p+1) and printing does not produce output

Tags: c, pointers

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void)
 {
    int a=10 ;
    int *p;
    p = &a;
    *(p+1) = 20;
    printf("The value at (p+1) is %d\n",*(p+1));

    return 0;
  }
```

I'm trying to do some pointer arithmetic and trying to implement the code. I'm trying to assign value 20 to next address in the memory using *(p+1) and print it using the printf statement, but my code isn't producing any output. Why is it so?

Comment: Pointers must point at validly-allocated memory.  You set `p` to point to `a`, which is fine, but then when you add one to `p`, you're pointing at some memory that isn't `a`, and chaos ensues. ***If*** `a` were an actual array, of two or more ints, this would work as you expect.

Comment: *I'm trying to assign value 20 to next address in the memory* And you're successfully doing that — except that the next address in memory isn't yours to modify.  It's kind of like, if you live in a large apartment building, you walk down the main hallway and into the door *next* to your front door, and start making coffee in the kitchen, and kissing the children, and your neighbor gets badly upset...

Comment: @ryyker: `*(p+1)` is not pointing anywhere; its type is `int`, not a pointer. `p+1` would point somewhere; it points to one beyond `a` and has defined behavior. `*(p+1)` does have undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Yes, you are right.   `*(p+1)` is a place one memory location beyond `a`.  (better ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually hits me in a very dubious manner. I get Segmentation fault in the code. We had different results.

Firstly, who gave you any guarantee that `p + 1` is even memory? It could very well be 0x00. No joke! You could be on a weird system in which the memory works backwards and if `&a` is 0x04, then `a + 1` would be 0x00. There is no system in which memory is backwards for some reason, but it could happen. I don't think the standard enforces anything related to this(correct me if I'm wrong). This would just create confusion, no wonder nobody has tried this.

Secondly, who gave you any guarantee that `p + 1` is not already used? The compiler might be using it, which it does very often.

Thirdly, who gave you any guarantee that picking up some memory that you haven't allocated will even work? Allocating memory is basically reserving memory, if you don't do that nothing is guaranteed to work. Imagine a bus. If you won't reserve a seat, there's no guarantee that you'll be able to sit on it.

So what happens? Undefined behaviour! Basically, if this situation is reached, then the compiler could make code that sends death threats to the president and enrols you for Militia training from a terrorist organisation and the compiler could still call itself "ISO/IEC 9899:2018 compliant". Unless there's an all-catching "compiler can't insert malicious code" phrase in the standard. I haven't checked. Yeah, this is why you should not use obscure compilers. Jokes aside, basically anything could happen, god and only god knows what will happen. Not even the compiler, not you, not ISO know what is going to happen. And that's why "undefined behaviour"s are so dreaded. Don't do weird stuff with memory.

Btw, the thing that makes this especially funny is that `&p`, with most compilers would be the same as `p + 1` on 32 bit systems. And it probably overlap in 64 bit systems. Note the word probably, there's no guarantee.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying here, regardless, it is the most _entertaining_ thing I have looked at all day. :)  (Kind of [Ricky Gervais-esk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Office_(British_TV_series)))

Comment: @ryyker I basically took out all of my anger of C being very lose-standard. I can't do anything but shed a tear for the large config files of C libraries that find out how to compile the code on every system. It even checks for `malloc`, this is just sad. These days, I've basically said lol to the standard and am using GNU C and using new C-like languages like Go for anything non critical.

Answer (score 2):

In the following:

```
int a=10 ;
```

When `a` is declared and initialized, 10 is placed in memory at the location it was created, as indicated in the following depiction of memory:

```
|?|10|?|...
  ^
  a
```

Then the statements

```
int *p;
p = &a;
```

create a pointer `p`, the set the pointer to point to the same location

```
|?|10|?|...
  ^
  p
```

In the statement `*(p+1) = 20;`

`*(p + 1)` references a place in memory that your process does not own, 1 memory location beyond `a`

```
    |?|10|?|...
         ^
```

attempting to assign a value there invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: So, this means *(p+1) won't even access the garbage value at that memory position?

Comment: @Electronics_seekhado_koi - Well, it is an attempt to do that.   it refers to a place one memory location beyond where `a` was created, and attempting to assign a value there, is what invokes undefined behavior, which means anything can happen, including a seg-fault.  [Even reading memory you do not own invokes UB](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP33-C.+Do+not+read+uninitialized+memory).

Comment: When I'm printing the value at (p+1) location without the assignment *(p+1) = 20 then it is giving the garbage value at the location but with the assignment statement it isn't even producing the garbage value? Is there any special reason for this behavior?

Comment: Printing `p+1` using `printf( "%p\n", p+1);`  should simply output that memory location. (i.e. not its contents, just its address)  But when attempting to access and output the contents there, `*(p+1)`,  because there is no way to determine what occupies that location, how would you know what format specifier to use?  Using the wrong format specifier alone is UB.  See link to reading memory you do not own in previous comment.

Comment: @Electronics_seekhado_koi "When I'm printing the value at (p+1) location without the assignment *(p+1) = 20 then it is giving the garbage value at the location  ..." --> No, it is _undefined behavior_.  There is no specified result of such code - a read does not even need to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way, `*(p + 1)` is the same as having `p[1]` this means you are looking for `a[1]` but `a` is not an array, `a[1]` does not exist in your program, you can't either read or write in that memory location, we don't really know what's in there, that is why your program suffers from [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3).

Answer (score 0):

'a' is an normal integer you cant navigate trough the elements because there are no elements.

it is just an normal pointer to a variable.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void)
 {
    int a[10];
    *(a+1) = 20;
    printf("The value at (p+1) is %d\n",*(a+1));

    return 0;
  }
```

i thinkt this is what you want